# Where to set env var for Debian12?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, environment-variables

There are too many places can hold permanent env var settings in Linux, so that I can't finger out which one is the most correct/proper.

1. /etc/environments
2. /etc/bash.bashrc
3. /etc/profile
4. /etc/profile.d/*
5. ~/.bash
6. ~/.profile

....

Now I need to set a env-var that is a path to a code base of my project, and this env-var should be shared with many users of my Debian-12.

Which method of above should I use?

In other words, which method is proper with my requestion?

Thanks!

Comment: What _consumes_ this environment variable? Is it a desktop program started from e.g. GNOME? Is it a command-line program started from a shell? Is it a service started from "systemctl --user"?

Comment: @u1686_grawity thanks!  I want to find a set of rules about setting env-vars on Debian, and then I will refer it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` is the traditional place for environment variables for all users, but these days `/etc/environment` may cover a little bit more.

These days, not all processes go through the same startup path; in practice with GNOME as your graphical interface there will be two parallel paths that have different configurations, *and* one of them may behave differently depending on whether you chose Wayland mode or the (soon to be removed) X11 mode for GNOME.

1. When you log in to anything at all, 'pam_env' is run as part of PAM and loads /etc/environment. This would be the most appropriate place for "system-wide" environment variables that have to apply to every kind of user session.
2. If an X11 session was chosen, GDM's Xsession script loads /etc/profile, /etc/xprofile, ~/.profile, ~/.xprofile (as 'sh' shell scripts – regardless of what shell you normally use). So /etc/xprofile would be a good place for anything that's inherently X11-specific.

   If a Wayland session was chosen, GDM loads nothing at all, but gnome-session provides similar behavior by restarting itself through your default login shell and will therefore load /etc/profile, ~/.profile (or ~/.bash_profile) if you are using Bash. So /etc/profile would be a good place for environment variables that apply to all GUI processes of either kind.

   In both cases, if /etc/profile is being run, it'll usually load /etc/profile.d/*.sh as well. Quite a few packages that need a certain enviroment variable do so through /etc/profile.d/.

   (If ~/.profile is being run through Bash, it will also explicitly load ~/.bashrc; however, I would generally *not* put global environment variables in bashrc, because in the X11 case ~/.profile is actually being run through /bin/sh which is not Bash on Debian.)
3. At the same time, the login causes a 'systemd --user' service manager to independently start in background. This *also* calls PAM on its own – including pam_env – so it'll start with everything that /etc/environment has.
4. The 'systemd --user' service manager loads everything from /etc/environment.d/ and ~/.config/environment.d/ (see 'man environment.d') before starting its "user-level" background services.
5. Now, gnome-session calls into 'systemd-user' and supplies the environment variables that it collected from steps 1-2 (basically does 'systemctl --user import-environment'), then asks it to start the rest of GNOME GUI. So the GUI apps will have a combination of environment variables from steps 1-2 and 3-4, as they actually descend from 'systemd-user' and not from GDM/gnome-session.
6. Finally, if the user opens a terminal app, the shell being run within that terminal window will generally load /etc/bash.bashrc, ~/.bashrc (but usually *not* the "profile" scripts). So anything defined in bashrc will be available to terminal windows but not to the rest of the system; it's a good place to put shell-specific stuff (not just environment but also aliases and such).

For SSH logins, the process is somewhat simpler as 'systemd-user' is not involved (it does start but remains in background and uninvolved with your login shell).

1. The SSH server calls 'pam_env' as well, loading /etc/environment.
2. The SSH server starts your login shell; if it's Bash, it will load /etc/profile (including .d/*.sh) and ~/.profile. Usually your ~/.profile will typically load ~/.bashrc.

Console (tty) logins work the same way (just with "The /sbin/login process" instead of "The SSH server").